# Get Asp Net Core's access_token in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-core

We've got an Asp Net Core MVC application, whith the following configuration to authenticate over the API:

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
   .AddCookie(opt =>
   {
      opt.Cookie.Name = "appName";
      opt.LoginPath = "/Account/SignIn";
      opt.LogoutPath = "/Account/Logout";
      opt.ReturnUrlParameter = "returnUrl";
   });
```

It uses HttpContext to store Bearer access_token:

```
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(identity), authProperties);
```

All the pages in the application are standard MVC views, but some of them have built-in AngularJS controllers.

How can we get access token in AngularJS controller to access the API?

Comment: If you are using Cookie authentication then you don't need a bearer token.

Comment: first you need to fatch foken from api and store in localstorage or sessionstorage of client side and fatch from them and pass in header of each and every request of API

Comment: @JasminSolanki, how to fetch token from api to an angularJs?